# NGINX reverse proxy with Rewrites to replace TMG2010

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, reverse-proxy

I curently have a Forefront TMG2010 doing reverse proxy to several internal web servers. Since it was really easy in TMG I have done lots of host and virtual directory mappings/rewrites.

Now I ened to acheive the same in NGINX.

e.g.,

apphost.domain.com/ needs to map internally to server1/apppath/

apphost.domain.com/test/ needs to map internally to server2/apppath/

apphost.domain.com/dev/ needs to map internally to server3/apppath/

in each case the internal /apppath/ needs to be invisible to the client. This is to achieve the same as the external to internal path mapping in TMG.

What I have done so far is;

```
server {

    listen  80;

    server_name  host.server.com;

    location /test/ {
    proxy_set_header    Host    $host;
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /app/$1 break;
        proxy_pass  http://10.0.0.2; 
    }

    location / {
    proxy_set_header    Host    $host;
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /app/$1 break;
    proxy_pass  http://10.0.0.1; 
        }
```

But only the / seems to work, the /test/ doesnt.

Help!

Comment: Do you want `/test/` to map to `http://10.0.0.2/app//test/`? You also have an extra `/` in there. You can also append a URI to the `proxy_pass` rather than using `rewrite ... break`. See: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass

Comment: Nope, I want to drop the /test internally.

Comment: Nope, I want to drop the /test internally, but it needs to remain displayed externally.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to map `/test/foo` to `http://10.0.0.2/app/foo`. The simplest solution is:

```
location /test/ {
  proxy_set_header    Host    $host;
  proxy_pass  http://10.0.0.2/app/; 
}
```

According to [the documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) the `/test/` element will be replaced by `/app/` as it passes upstream.